# image display from database in php

Tags: php, sql

i want to display image from database and below is my code where empid is the value of textbox, it's showing the image name stored in database but i am not able to echo this picture. anyone can help in this regard.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM info WHERE empid= $empid");
$result->bindParam('$empid', $empid);
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $rows = $result->fetch(); $i++){

echo $rows['image']; 


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line.

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM info WHERE empid= '". $empid ."'");
```

Comment: it is display the name of image.this not display the image

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Out a var_dump($row); in the for, and look which item in array is path of image . then use img html tag and put the row['image'] in src attribute.

Comment: <img src="images/<?php echo $rows['image']; ?>" width="150" height="150" >

Comment: @MuhammadUsman :| Ok
`<img src="your_image_path/ ".$row['image']." ">`

Comment: echo "<img src="images/ '.$row["image"].' ">"; this is not working

Comment: echo '<img src="images/".$row["image"]. > ' ; this is not picking up the path

Answer (score 1):

its only show you the filename that you stored in your db . if you want to show image then first add folder location with image name and pass into the `<img src="excatImageLocation">`

Example -

```
$yourExactPath = "YourImageUploadFolderLocation".$rows['image']; // img/yourFilename.jpg;
echo "<img src='$yourExactPath' />
```

Comment: i want to search against id

Comment: the code i run that is only display the image name..this is not display the image against empid

Comment: if its showing right image name then you just need to pass your folder path with image name . DB only store image name but iu also need to store image in a folder.

Comment: how can i pass the name of image.while i am searching against different ids

Comment: this will give me the same image on every search

Comment: you dont need to pass image name u just need to pass image location with $rows['image']; in img src attribute.

Comment: <img src="your_image_path/ ".$row['image']." "> this is not going to be work

Comment: you stored images in a folder or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You either concatenate the id onto the text string containing the query or use a parameter place holder and then bind a value to it. Not both, as you were doing.

The most secure way is to use parameters.

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT image FROM info WHERE empid= :empid");
$result->bindParam(':empid', $empid, , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['image']; 
}
?>
```